# Controls.add -> Controls.clear -> Controls.add automatically set focus the last added control?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have code like below.

When the form is loaded, the textBox2 appears automatically **selected** and in focus.

The calling sequence has to be like below. It would not be reproduced otherwise.

Why's that?

```
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
this.Controls.Clear();
this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
```

[image]

The code is just an example of the real life scenario where controls are dynamically loaded.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the point of adding the first textbox if you are clearing it anyways? It does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the textBox2 control on your form, there's only one place the focus can be.  If you want to set the focus order of your controls, use the `TabIndex` property.

Comment: besides focus, why it is also appears selected?

Comment: What do you mean by "selected?"

Comment: Please refer to the screen shot above